# How do I build this into a formula?

Tags: formula

I'm looking to have a milestone fire based off the following 3 criteria:

- Case: Case Origin = 'Email - Support'
- Case: First Manual Email Response = 'blank'
- CreatedBy.UserRole.Id = 00E60000000mH2J

Can someone help me put this into a formula format?

Comment: If you are creating a workflow rule then what have you tried, where are you stuck. Seems this is the most basic of admin tasks and can be done simply by following the prompts on the screen. You already seem to have everything you need here just plug in those values

Comment: I cannot do criteria based because I cannot access the "CreatedBy.UserRole.Id' -- it needs to be a formula, but I cannot figure out how to format the Formula.

Comment: Why not just ask that?

Comment: Sorry, just thought having all the context of what I need the formula to accomplish would be important in my question. Can you help me put this into a formula format? Case: Case Origin = 'Email - Support'
Case: First Manual Email Response = 'blank'
CreatedBy.UserRole.Id = 00E60000000mH2J

Comment: Right the add details are important but the crux of your question was the fact that you did not know how to get the UserRole Id because it was not in the pick list to select. Just trying to help you form questions that get answers. Had you not clarified many would not have answered as it appears that you put no effort into resolving the issue on your own and just wanted someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the Workflow Rule formula change the "Run this rule if the following" to `formula evaluates to true`

Then use `CreatedBy.UserRoleId` in the formula along with your other criteria

So something like

```
AND(

   ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Email - Support'),
   ISBLANK(First_Manual_Response__c),
   CreatedBy.UserRoleId = '00E60000000mH2J' //May need to change this to the 18 chr Id

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much- I've added the below, but am getting this error: "Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'AND()'. Expected Boolean, received DateTime" because the manual email response field is a date/time field. What would I need to adjust in order for this criteria to become true?  AND(

   ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Email - Support'),
    First_Manual_Email_Response__c,
   CreatedBy.UserRoleId = '00E60000000mH2JEAU' 
)

Comment: @KateHolden - Basic debugging. I misread and though it was a boolean. Answer updated.

Comment: Awesome, this worked- thank you so much for all your help!!!

Comment: @KateHolden - Since you are new here also keep in mind if an answer solved your problem please consider upvoting and marking it as accepted so others with similar questions can find answers.